# Memory leak taking a photo with Chrome or webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin, webview

My web app need to take multiple photo for each user journey (8 to 13 photos).
But the third Process will crash with an error **"unable to complete previous operation due to low memory"**
It crash when we take a photo. I don't have to answer "keep or retake" the picture, it crash when we take the photo.

I tried two different way to make the web app. One using Chrome only, the other with Xamarin and webview. Both failed with the same result (the only difference is webview/xamarin just crash without any error).

In both case, I take only two photo, upload them to the server, and I update the DOM by deleting the photos after uploading them on the server(and a little more) so it won't stay in Memory

```
while (focus.children[0].children[1].firstChild)
    focus.children[0].children[1].removeChild(focus.children[0].children[1].firstChild);
```

(code from stackoverflow)

Also I add some meta to force the code to be loaded at each use

```
<meta http-equiv=“Pragma” content=”no-cache”>
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
```

(code also from stackoverflow)

In the xamarin/webview case I also delete the webview and call the GC.Collect / WaitForPendingFinalizers.
The photo is also compressed and it size is reduced (file is something like 200ko).

The device I use only have 2GB of memory. It work better with more RAM, but that's not the issue here... Since I am able to complete the process more than once.

Do you know how I can spot the memory leak and how I can correct it.

Comment: can't you use leak canary lib https://github.com/crehmann/LeakCanaryBinding ?  It help you to detect the leak and give you more details about the issus

Comment: Thx for the link.
Tried it (made the process a few times) and it made 4 dumps. But the detected leaks are logged with only 761 octets. It can't explain the issue unfortunately.

Comment: It is one of the most common errors many Android users encounter while trying to upload a file using a web browser.You could try to go into “Developer Options” menu,scroll down and uncheck the “Don’t Keep Activities” options to turn it off.

Comment: @Leo Zhu, thx for the advice, but I already tried it.
But it's not working fine. Since Android is taking the photo and not the webview (custom behavior, I notify xamarin using a jsbridge and I take the picture with MediaPicker that allow me to resize and compress it before showinf it on my webview and sending it to the server).
Checking the "don't keep activity" close my app when the camera is open...

Comment: Did you try to call GC.Collect in the `OnLowMemory` method in your `MainActivity` ?